# Fixed payment is returned as 0. Why? What corrections to make?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Now write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. By a fixed monthly payment, we mean a single number which does not change each month, but instead is a constant amount that will be paid each month.
>
> In this problem, we will not be dealing with a minimum monthly payment rate.
>
> The following variables contain values as described below:
>
> - `balance` - the outstanding balance on the credit card
> - `annualInterestRate` - annual interest rate as a decimal
>
> The program should print out one line: the lowest monthly payment that will pay off all debt in under 1 year, for example:
>
> ```
> Lowest Payment: 180
> ```
>
> Assume that the interest is compounded monthly according to the balance at the end of the month (after the payment for that month is made). The monthly payment must be a multiple of $10 and is the same for all months. Notice that it is possible for the balance to become negative using this payment scheme, which is okay. A summary of the required math is found below:
>
> - Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12.0
> - Monthly unpaid balance = (Previous balance) - (Minimum fixed monthly payment)
> - Updated balance each month = (Monthly unpaid balance) + (Monthly interest rate x Monthly unpaid balance)

Here is my code. I do not know where I'm going wrong:

```
balance = float(raw_input('enter the outsanding balance on your card'))
annualInterestRate  = float(raw_input('enter the anual interest rate as a decimal'))
month = 0
checkBalance = balance
monthlyFixedPayment = 0
while checkBalance <= 0:
    checkBalance = balance
    monthlyFixedPayment += 10
    while month <= 11:
        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12.0
        monthlyUnpaidBalance = checkBalance - monthlyFixedPayment
        checkBalance = monthlyUnpaidBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * monthlyUnpaidBalance)
print('lowest payment:' + str(monthlyFixedPayment))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the program you are looking for:

```
balance = 500
annualInterestRate = .5
checkBalance = balance
monthlyFixedPayment = 10
count = 0
while checkBalance > 0:
    month = 0
    while month <= 11 and checkBalance > 0:
        count+=1
        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12.0
        monthlyUnpaidBalance = checkBalance - monthlyFixedPayment
        checkBalance = monthlyUnpaidBalance - (monthlyInterestRate * monthlyUnpaidBalance)
        print "\t"+str(checkBalance)
        month+=1
    print checkBalance

print "lowest amount: "
print count*monthlyFixedPayment+checkBalance
```

I have left the print statements, so that you can see what is going on in each iteration.

Some problems i noticed in your code:

1) you were doing a `monthlyFixedPayment += 10` that was changing the fixed payemnt. you are not supposed to change the fixed payment according to your problem definition.

2) you were doing a `checkBalance = balance` in each iteration of outer `while` loop. This was causing the calculated value to be resetted.

3) I have introduced a count variable to check how many times these decuctions were happening, as month was getting reset in each iteration.

Comment: Identify the differences between his code and yours, and explain why you changed them.

Comment: @codefrenzy: he was changing the `monthlyFixedPayment` because he is trying to find the proper value for it; it's kind of the whole point of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

`while checkBalance <= 0:` to `while checkBalance >= 0:`

Also, you need to increment `month` in the `while month <= 11:` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are going at it the hard way; there is an analytic solution for fixed_payment:

```
from math import ceil

def find_fixed_monthly_payment(balance, months, yearly_rate):
    i = 1. + yearly_rate / 12.
    im = i ** months
    return balance * (im * (1. - i)) / (i * (1. - im))

def find_final_balance(balance, months, yearly_rate, fixed_payment):
    i = 1. + yearly_rate / 12.
    for _ in range(months):
        # make payment
        balance -= fixed_payment
        # add interest
        balance *= i
    return balance

def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            # input could not be cast to float; try again
            pass

def main():
    balance     = get_float("Please enter starting balance: ")
    annual_rate = get_float("Annual interest rate (in percent): ") / 100.

    fixed_payment = find_fixed_monthly_payment(balance, 12, annual_rate)

    # round up to the nearest $10
    fixed_payment = ceil(fixed_payment / 10.) * 10.

    # double-check value of fixed_payment:
    assert find_final_balance(balance, 12, annual_rate, fixed_payment      ) <= 0., "fixed_payment is too low!"
    assert find_final_balance(balance, 12, annual_rate, fixed_payment - 10.)  > 0., "fixed_payment is too high!"

    print("Lowest payment: ${:0.2f}".format(fixed_payment))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```